# How can I use jquery's .get function to create a variable?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to use Jquery's `.get` function (below) to return a simple text value, either 0 or 1 and turn that value into a variable.  Here's what I am trying

```
jQuery.get( url, [data,] [success(data, textStatus, jqXHR),] [dataType] )
```

with my url being myexternalsite.com/text.txt

can i use a text file to simply return either a 0 or 1 and how do I make this a variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you're running a callback function. just use the "data" of your callback function and set the variable you want e.g. `myvariable = data`

Answer (score 0):

yes you can use anything you want.

```
var myVariable;
$.get(url,function(data){
    myVariable = data;
    alert('the variable has been initialised');
});
```

Ajax calls are restricted to the same domain, so an ajax call to an external site ("myexternalsite.com") is forbidden. For that you should use a proxy; this way, your url variable would be something like `url = 'myProxy.php?url=myexternalsite.com/text.txt'`